# Would a Socket Connection Outperform an Intarvaled Database Sweep and Requests?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm building a small chat application to add to an existing framework.  There will only be *20-50* users **maximum** at any one time.

I was wondering if I could get away with u*pdating a cache file* containing (semi) live chat data for whichever users happen to be chatting just by *performing timed queries and regular AJAX refreshes* for new data as opposed to learning how to *open and maintain a socket connection*.

I'm sure there are existing chat plug-ins out there, but I just had a hell of a time installing one and I could see building the whole damn thing taking just as much time as plugging one in.

**Am I off to a bad start?**

Thanks in advance -J

(p.s. this is a semi closed network behind a php login so security isn't a great concern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest reading up on JavaScript [Long Polling](http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2009/05/04/php-jquery-ajax-javascript-long-polling/) to retrieve your data instantaneously.

As far as collecting and distributing your data, I would recommend you use a database that supports `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY`. (For example, Postgres provides you with [pg_get_notify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-get-notify.php) in PHP)

With long-polling and a notification-enabled database like Postgres, you could easily build a real-time, scalable chat application.

Other resources and links:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-get-notify.php
- http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2009/05/04/php-jquery-ajax-javascript-long-polling/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29
- http://www.webdevelopmentbits.com/avoiding-long-polling

Answer (score 0):

I second that long polling is a good approach. However, understanding it, and doing it correctly, is far more difficult than just polling in intervals. With 20-50 users, scalability shouldn't be an issue. For a good long polling design, you should look at how you can avoid to suspend a server thread for the lifetime of an http request.

It could be wise to start out with a simple polling approach, advancing to long polling later on.